# Slice proporcional ao tamanho do dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Como eu posso realizar um slice no dataframe de acordo com o seu tamanho de linhas?

Por exemplo: se o dataframe tiver 14 linhas, dividir em 2 partes de 7, se tiver 28 linhas, dividir em 3 partes de 7, e assim sucessivamente.

Há alguma função própria do pandas para realizar isto?

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.array_split()`

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
   ...:                           'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
   ...:                    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
   ...:                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
   ...:                    'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8)})

In [3]: print df
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -0.174067 -0.608579
1  bar    one -0.860386 -1.210518
2  foo    two  0.614102  1.689837
3  bar  three -0.284792 -1.071160
4  foo    two  0.843610  0.803712
5  bar    two -1.514722  0.870861
6  foo    one  0.131529 -0.968151
7  foo  three -1.002946 -0.257468

In [4]: np.array_split(df, 3)
Out[4]: 
[     A    B         C         D
0  foo  one -0.174067 -0.608579
1  bar  one -0.860386 -1.210518
2  foo  two  0.614102  1.689837,
      A      B         C         D
3  bar  three -0.284792 -1.071160
4  foo    two  0.843610  0.803712
5  bar    two -1.514722  0.870861,
      A      B         C         D
6  foo    one  0.131529 -0.968151
7  foo  three -1.002946 -0.257468]
```